# Filtering in dplyr with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Trying to find the best way to do this. I am trying to output a table that only contains records that fulfills a condition of 2022 counts > 2021 counts. The table below is what I currently have from the original df. Not sure where to go next from here.

| year | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Bob | 22 |
| 2021 | Joe | 3 |
| 2021 | Meg | 4 |
| 2022 | Bob | 30 |
| 2022 | Joe | 1 |
| 2022 | Meg | 10 |

Resulting Table:

| year | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Bob | 30 |
| 2022 | Meg | 10 |

The script that I have so far that got me to the top df:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year = format(as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y"), name) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  filter(year == c("2022", "2021") )
```

Answer (score 3):

We may `arrange` the data by 'name', 'year', then grouped by 'name', `filter` the groups having the second count greater than the `first` and the 'year' is 2022

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(name, year) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(nth(count, 2) > first(count), year == 2022) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   year name  count
  <int> <chr> <int>
1  2022 Bob      30
2  2022 Meg      10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L
), name = c("Bob", "Joe", "Meg", "Bob", "Joe", "Meg"), count = c(22L, 
3L, 4L, 30L, 1L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach for your example:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice_max(count) %>% 
  filter(year == 2022)
```

```
   year name  count
  <int> <chr> <int>
1  2022 Bob      30
2  2022 Meg      10
```